# Converting integrate(ln(x-4)) Output

Tags: sympy

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x
integrate(ln(x-4))
```

Outputs:

`log(−4)−−4log(−4)`

Is there a way I can convert this to `(x-4)*ln(x-4) - (x-4)` or `(x-4)*ln(x-4) + 4 -x`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a manual substitution using `transform`:

```
In [2]: I = Integral(ln(x - 4), x)

In [3]: I
Out[3]: 
⌠              
⎮ log(x - 4) dx
⌡              

In [4]: I.transform(x - 4, y)
Out[4]: 
⌠          
⎮ log(y) dy
⌡          

In [5]: I.transform(x - 4, y).doit()
Out[5]: y⋅log(y) - y

In [6]: I.transform(x - 4, y).doit().subs(y, x - 4)
Out[6]: -x + (x - 4)⋅log(x - 4) + 4
```

Alternatively you can just use `collect`:

```
In [7]: integrate(ln(x - 4))
Out[7]: x⋅log(x - 4) - x - 4⋅log(x - 4)

In [8]: integrate(ln(x - 4)).collect(log(x - 4))
Out[8]: -x + (x - 4)⋅log(x - 4)
```

This case misses the `4` but that's expected because antiderivatives are only uniquely defined up to an additive constant.